# Flutter: Depreciated Splash Screens Removal

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I would like to remove the depreciated splash screens in my Flutter Project.
I have never written code for a splash screen so it must be a default file from when the project was created.

The Flutter documentation is not informative for helping me locate the files I need to edit/remove.
The flutter doctor command is not showing any error with flutter.

Debug Console:
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 2741): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.

I need someone to help me locate the default files for a splash screen.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove these lines in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data 
  android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" 
  android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```

Comment: This worked for removing the debug console message.  Thank you.